# Подскажите расширение vscode для styled-components, для подсветки элементов в коде

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scss, styled-components

Решил попробывать styled-components но не подсвечиваются элементы, подскажите расширение пожалуйста.

Вот так у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так хочу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components (первая ссылка в гугле:))

Comment: Забей, я тупой, 3 дня за компом сидел, забыл что гугл есть

Answer (score 0):

Установи плагин в vs code и будет тебе счастье - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components.